# Tips for Exploring kubernetes ingress on AWS using kops

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kops

I have a working Kubernetes gossip-based cluster deployed on AWS using Kops.  I am planning to learn more about ingress this weekend. For this purpose I have gone through various documents and other material.
Can someone advise me on different things to look out for to pre-empt any issues I might face?

R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have similar setup of kubernetes cluster.

1. We have faced a problem with every implementation of `ingress controller`. By default it adds to registered targets all nodes in the cluster. Maybe at first this seems like a good idea because `kube-proxy` can correctly route the traffic via any node. We have various type of EC2 instances and some pods with heavy network usage on instances that support high network traffic. We had to write our own ingress controller to achieve what we want. Maybe this has changed and I would love to know if that has happened.
2. It's easy to spawn multiple ALB's but you will pay for every one of them additionally (it's not free). You can lower the cost because it's support `host` and `path` based routing.

We don't have any issues right now with `ingress`.

Have a look at different controllers and pick best one to suit your needs. I can give you a list of which I know and have looked at:

- https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx
- https://github.com/appscode/voyager
- https://github.com/coreos/alb-ingress-controller

Comment: Am learning ingress so that I avoid multiple load balancers. Thats point 2 you mentioned. Will go through your urls. The first one I seen before. I am also learning ingress because I hope to use it as a central means of implementing say JWT token based or Oath based access control. Any views on that goal?

Comment: Totally achievable. I don't think ingress will be a problem.

Comment: Thanks. Will request you to watch my posts and be around to help if I need it. Thanks.